# Не могу изменить несколько записей из БД

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Есть таблица Фильмов,Актеров и таблица соединяющая ид фильма и ид актера. Есть разметка.

`echo '<div class="actors-wrap">';
             foreach ($adminActors as $actor) {
                echo '<div class="genre-name">';
                    echo '<input class="option-input checkbox" type="checkbox" name="actor[]" value="'.$actor['id_actors'].'">';
                    echo '<span class="text"> '.$actor['firstName'].'</span>.';
                echo '</div>';
            }
            echo '</div>';`

получаю активные чекбоксы

```
$actors = $_POST['actor'];
```

получаю ид актеров кто снимался в фильме (который надо будет изменит потом)

```
$sqlActors = "SELECT * FROM film_actors WHERE  film_actors.`id_film`=" . $id;
```

Собственно запрос где я изменяю на нужных мне актеров

```
                foreach ($actors as $actor) {
                $sglA="UPDATE `film_actors` SET `id_actor` = $actor WHERE `id_film` =". $id;
                $item = $dataBase->executeRun($sglA);

            }
```

Но проблема  в том что, если актеров несколько например два, и изменить надо двое актеров то , эти два поля актеров хранят в себе два одинаковых актера. последний просто дублируется 2 раза один последний актер.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь понятно разложил )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы же своим запросом обновляете все записи в бд в которых id_film = $id

Не по одной записи, а все. 
Соответственно последнее значение из массива $actors  и будет значением для всех записей. 
Вам скорее тут скорее нужно либо менять конкретных актеров на других,
То-есть:

```
$sglA="UPDATE `film_actors` SET `id_actor` = $actor 
     WHERE `id_actor` = $oldActorId 
     AND `id_film` =". $id;
```

а лучше либо удалять записи и новые создавать.